# stringWithContentsOfFile can't convert my file and I don't know why

Tags: ios, json

I'm trying to parse a json file to import in inside Core Data of my app. I'm using Rubymotion but it doesn't matter, the error is related to `stringWithContentsOfFile`.

Or better, the error is in my Json file.

[Here](http://media.dday.it/roby/q.json)

I export the file from a rails backend, and I load it with my app...

```
seed_file = NSBundle.mainBundle.pathForResource('converted', ofType:'json')
json_string = String.new(NSString.stringWithContentsOfFile(seed_file))
```

When I try to load my json I receive this error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString appendString:]: nil argument'
***
```

I think is something related some special char, maybe the encoding. I try to cut some pieces of json and it load

```
json_string = String.new(NSString.stringWithContentsOfFile(seed_file, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
=> "[\n  {\n    \"id\": 5306,\n    \"quiz_type\": \"oltre\",\n    \"text\": \"Su quale pubblicazione dell\\'Istituto Idrografico della Marina si possono ricavare informazioni pi√π specifiche sulle maree?\",\n    \"flagged\": false,\n    \"image\": {\n      \"image\": {\n        \"url\": \"\"\n      }\n    },\n    \"section\": {\n      \"id\": 6,\n      \"name\": \"Navigazione\"\n    },\n    \"answers\": [\n      {\n        \"id\": 5185,\n        \"text\": \"Sul Portolano\",\n        \"correct\": false\n      },\n      {\n        \"id\": 5186,\n        \"text\": \"Sulle Effemeridi Nautiche\",\n        \"correct\": false\n      },\n      {\n        \"id\": 5187,\n        \"text\": \"Sulle Tavole di marea\",\n        \"correct\": true\n      }\n    ]\n  },\n  {\n    \"id\": 5305,\n    \"quiz_type\": \"oltre\",\n    \"text\": \"Cosa indica Zo?\",\n    \"flagged\": false,\n    \"image\": {\n      \"image\": {\n        \"url\": \"\"\n      }\n    },\n    \"section\": {\n      \"id\": 6,\n      \"name\": \"Navigazione\"\n    },\n    \"answers\": [\n      {\n        \"id\": 5182,\n        \"text\": \"La differenza tra alta e bassa marea sizigiale\",\n        \"correct\": false\n      }
```

But when I try to parse the string I receive an error for some char in my json: for example I have **pi√π** instead of **più**

Where is the fault?

Comment: Your file must be valid UTF-8. Maybe it isn't. And there is no need to convert to a string, you can pass either the file url or an NSData object with the contents of the file to the parser; saves time and memory.

Comment: @gnasher729 I know. But I try to load my Json in a lot of toold for validation, also Cocoa Json Editor for OSX and I loads fine!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get the data from the file. Then you can either get a string, or go straight for the deserialized JSON object.

```
    // get file handle
    let seedFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("q", ofType:"json")
    // get raw data
    let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: seedFile!)
    // get string from data...
    let string = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    // ...or get array of objects from data
    let array = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: nil) as [AnyObject]
```

Comment: The problem is in NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding). It return me an error.

Try with the json file!

Comment: The code works with the file provided [http://media.dday.it/roby/q.json](http://media.dday.it/roby/q.json). @RobertoPezzali How did you download the file?

Comment: I change the json 1 hour ago. Now the problem is the parsing: in my object text value I have some string with strange characters...

Comment: @RobertoPezzali I downloaded the file again, and the code worked.  The string **pi√π** looks like incorrect encoding, like a problem saving or opening the file. I got **più**.